# Import CSV data from internet to mathematica

Tags: import, data, web-access, csv-format, compression

This [Link](https://www.oecd.org/sti/ind/inter-country-input-output-tables.htm) has data in CSV format for 2015 and other years. I would like to get the data for 2015 (by clicking on 2015) but the CSV data format has more rows than Excel can handle and therefore the data transfer is carried out only for the limited number of rows.

Is there any way to import the complete data set for 2015 into Mathematica?

Comment: What you get by clicking that link is a ZIP file, not a CSV, so you would have to import it in MMA as such first. How big is it?

Comment: @MarcoB: Yes, sorry for that. I save the ZIP and expand it to get the raw data file. Then I want to import the data into Mathematica without trying to open it because opening the file is a problem and I want to circumvent that by directly importing it to MMA.

Comment: @MarcoB: I forgot to let you know that the file has at most 3000 rows and 3000 columns (a square matrix).

Comment: There is no way that those dimensions are a problem for Excel. It can handle up 
1,048,576 rows ($2^{20}$) by 16,384 ($2^{14}$) columns (see the [format specs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)). Your problem lies elsewhere, or those dimensions are wrong.

Comment: @MarcoB: I use ODT opensource software, but save the data in XLS format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just download and unzip the CSV file and then run:

```
data = Import["path/to/ICIO2018_2015.CSV"];
Dimensions[data]
```

> {2552, 2876}